# Ansible: Wait until time

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I need some help with an ansible-playbook.
Situation:
We need a irregular update for some development systems. For our application, some large files have to been send via network. To not risk the daily work cycle we want to use ansible to do this (if requested) at a specific time at night.

Here is the Problem: Can a command pause the script until the defined time is reached (without using AWX regular schedules)???
Can anyone note an example of how to use the existing mechanics?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
- name: Sleep for 60 seconds and continue with play
  wait_for:
   timeout: 60
```

Comment: Hi. more like.

`- name: Wait until 6:25 AM
  pause:
    stop: 06:25:00.000000`

Answer (score 0):

Then, you may need something like this. This is the extension of the previous approach.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
   var_wait_time: "18:25:00"
   var_wait_datetime: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}-{{ ansible_date_time.month }}-{{ ansible_date_time.day }} {{ var_wait_time }}"
   var_current_datetime: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }} {{ ansible_date_time.time }}"
  tasks:
  - name: "Calcualte the seconds to pause the play."
    set_fact:
     var_wait_seconds: "{{ ((var_wait_datetime | to_datetime) - (var_current_datetime | to_datetime)).total_seconds() }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
  - name: "Show the datetimes and seconds to play the pause."
    debug:
     msg: "{{ var_wait_datetime }} :: {{ var_current_datetime }} :: {{ var_wait_seconds }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
  - name: "Pause the play for {{ var_wait_seconds }} seconds."
    wait_for:
     timeout: "{{ var_wait_seconds }}"
    when: var_wait_seconds | int  > 0
```